# How to open headless browser in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

lets say i have used with selenium
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

but now i want the browser to open. Is this possible? thanks

Comment: Please help us help you. Show what you have attempted and refer to [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you use headless then its not possible to open the browser.
You must have to remove the headless code to open the browser.

Comment: No, this is not supported. If you need a headed browser, start it without the headless options to begin with.

Comment: It is impossible @paulle

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn’t possible.

The `--headless` option is a command-line flag used to instantiate the browser, meaning it is being told to execute headlessly for the entirety of its existence.